# Is it possible to tell whether an email was received due to error vs due to being bcc-ed?

Tags: email

I recently received an email and saw that neither my email address nor any mailing group I am a part of was in the "To" or "CC" headers. I could not find any indication that I was an intended recipient, even after examining the raw headers. Based on this, I felt it was likely that I received the email in error (as in software error), so I notified all addressed parties and the sender. The sender informed me that I had been BCC-ed.

Other than asking the recipient, is there any way I could have known that I was BCC-ed rather than an erroneous recipient?

Note: I found a few questions on other Q&A networks regarding this and almost all of the replies were written as though the asker had asked how to tell which other BCC recipients may exist. That is not what is being asked here.

This question appears to address the situation, but the answers do not mention the possibility of receiving the message in error: [How can I tell whether I was BCCed to a MIME message?](https://superuser.com/questions/812617/how-can-i-tell-whether-i-was-bcced-to-a-mime-message)

Comment: Only the originator knows if it is BCC'ed. "Bcc stands for blind carbon copy which is similar to that of Cc except that the Email address of the recipients specified in this field do not appear in the received message header and the recipients in the To or Cc fields will not know that a copy sent to these address."...https://www.cityu.edu.hk/csc/deptweb/support/faq/email/ccbcc.htm

Answer (score 2):

Errors are possible but EXCEPTIONALLY UNLIKELY on this scale.

When you receive an email and cannot see your own address, the simplest explanation is the best, and that is that you were BCC'd.